# Hyper-V: No ability to restart / change / create VM - exiting VMs running fine

Tags: windows, hyper-v, hyper-virtualization

on windows server 2022 with version 21Hs OS Build 20348.1607 I have Hyper V running. The Host System is an AMD Based Dell R7525 with NVME Storage. After having put one VM into saved state recently I had tried to start the VM afterwards. This did not work. The VM appears as "starting..." for multiple hours with no response.

I have afterwards moved the VM to another physical server and was able to easily start it from there.

What is very strange now is that all VMs are running on the questionable system yet:

a) I cannot open any of the settings of any system

b) I cannot create a new VM

c) trying to shutdown and start the VM renders in the same behaviour.

What I have done:

- Restarted VMMS and tried the procedure again - no response

Unluckily no windows events show any suitable output with current entries.

Also trying to create a VM from the power-shell renders no provisioning of the system.

The user to manage is in the domain admins and hyper-v admins group.

I am reluctant to restart the HV Host Service or the Hyper-V Host Compute Service - as I do not yet understand the potential consequences of doing so. Doing this on another comparable Dell R7525 server proved to work fine, yet I would really prefer to understand the issue on the questionable Hyper-V Host Server. Doing SFC Scan or DSIM provided no unhealthy output. Any suggestions of where I could look further ?

Thanks